# build para node.js back end

Tags: nodejs, express

Quería consultar sobre la realización de un build para mi proyecto node.js, usando express.
Básicamente lo que hace mi proyecto es recibir y enviar data de un data.json hacia otro proyecto en reactadmin.
La build de mi proyecto react admin la puedo hacer correctamente.
Lo que no entiendo es si es necesario hacer un build de mi proyecto node.js que sólo funciona del lado del servidor.
Esta carpeta pesa 2,3mb.
En el caso de ser necesario, no comprendo cómo se hace el build.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: si estas creando un servidor node que envia datos al cliente, puedes crear endpoints en el servidor para obtener los datos desde el cliente, asi mismo, estas subiendo dos proyectos a produccion. 
1- el cliente de reactadmin. 
2- el servidor node.
de esta manera el cliente obtiene los datos mediante consultas al servidor

Comment: Claro, eso es lo que yo hice. La consulta era si yo tengo que hacer un build del servicio de node. Me funciona perfecto sin hacerlo. Pero no se si es lo correcto